# My MacBook Pro freezes up when working with Parallels Desktop 11

Tags: performance, virtualization, parallels-desktop

This is the MacBook that I have: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
For some reason it started to freeze up randomly forcing me to restart, I don't really know why this happens. Every time this happens I'm programming in Visual Studio 2013 in Parallels Desktop, the settings for the virtual machine aren't very challenging so it shouldn't be because of the heat.

How can I see what causes my MacBook to freeze up? Are there some log files that I could post to see what causes this weird issue?

I do have a valid license of Parallels Desktop 11 and have the latest version of the program and macOS.

Comment: Parallels 11 _isn't_ the latest version, which is 12.1.1. I don't think Parallels 11 supports Sierra, so that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallels desktop 11 does not support macOS Sierra.

Requirements According to their [Knowledge Base](http://kb.parallels.com/en/123276):

> **Software**:
>
> - OS X El Capitan 10.11.1 or later
> - OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 or later
> - OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 or later